# Is this correct for Rudin exercise 3.7? Prove the series is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

This is Baby Rudin exercise 7 of Chapter 3. Prove that the convergence of $\sum{a_n}$ implies the convergence of $\sum{\sqrt {a_k} \over k}$ if $a_n \ge 0$.

Proof: 
I will attempt to show that the cauchy criterion is met so $${\sum_{k=n}^m {\sqrt {a_k} \over k}} \le \epsilon $$ for all $n,m \le N_1$. Im disregarding the absolute value since its all positive terms.

Since $\sum{a_n}$ converges, we know that the $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} a_n =0$ So there exists some $N_2$ such that for all $n \ge N_2$, $$   a_n \lt \ {{(m-n)}^2k^2(\epsilon)^2} $$ I am again disregarding the absolute values because its always positive Let N=max{$N_1,N_2$} then for all $n,m \ge N$ $$\sum_{k=n}^m {\sqrt {a_k} \over k} \le \sum_{k=n}^m {\sqrt {{(m-n)}^2k^2(\epsilon)^2} \over k} \le \sum_{k=n}^m{(m-n)(\epsilon)} = \epsilon $$

Maybe this is just crazy, should I just use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and forget about this or could I possibly make this method work?

Comment: Some of these steps seem dodgy. I'm not certain how you arrived at that bound on $a_n$, but I'm fairly certain your $N_2$ will depend on at least $k$, which seems like it would break your argument.

Comment: The bound is from the fact that for a series to be convergent, the limit of the sequence must be 0. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LimitTest.html and then that means it is less than any arbitrary epsilon (past some N). The k would depend on $N_2$, but why is that an issue?

Comment: I'm also not certain where you've gotten your $N_1$ from. Wasn't it what you wanted to find in the first place? As for the $N_2$, you definitely can't have $k$ depend on $N_2$, because you don't have control over $k$; in your argument $k$ ranges between $n$ and $m$. Eventually, you want your $N$ to depend only on $\varepsilon$ and the sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ that you began with.

Comment: $2|\sqrt{a_{n}}/n| \le |a_{n}|+1/n^{2}$ because $2|ab| \le |a|^{2}+|b|^{2}$.

Answer (score 5):

How about trying Cauchy-Schwarz:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sqrt{a_n}}n
\le\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\right)^{1/2}
\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}\right)^{1/2}
$$

---

You can use Cauchy-Schwarz to make the estimate in your question.
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=n}^m\frac{\sqrt{a_k}}k
&\le\left(\sum_{k=n}^m a_k\right)^{1/2}
\left(\sum_{k=n}^m\frac1{k^2}\right)^{1/2}\\
&\le\frac\pi{\sqrt6}\left(\sum_{k=n}^m a_k\right)^{1/2}
\end{align}
$$
which can be made small by the convergence of $\sum\limits_{k=n}^m a_k$.

Comment: Yeah I know thats the easier way, I wrote that at the bottom, I was just wondering if this also worked, and if not, what was wrong with it.

Comment: Hi @robjohn, I just finished writing a proof (and submitting this as a new question on MSE to hopefully get some feedback) in which I also applied the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, then I found this link and saw that you made a similar first move, in proving convergence of a series of products.  My question is:  does the inequality still hold, with n going to infinity?  So, we are effectively working in an infinite-dimensional inner product space, viewing the entries of each sequence as entries in an n-tuple coordinate vector.  Also, feel free to comment on my question post :-)  Thanks so much,

Comment: I am really hoping that it works, since this avoids the bit more messy and more technical summation by parts methods... @robjohn

Comment: Do we even need Cauchy-Schwarz, i.e. I think it suffices to observe directly that $\sqrt{a_k}/k < a_k$  for each $k$, which gives the inequality $\sum_{k=n}^m\sqrt(a_k)/k < \sum_{k=n}^{m}a_k?$

Comment: @jesterII: why is that true? suppose $a_3=\frac1{100}$, then $\frac{\sqrt{a_3}}3=\frac1{30}\gt\frac1{100}=a_3$