# Rudin chap 3 exercise 7.

Tags: sequences-and-series

The question is basically to prove that convergence of $\sum{a_n}$  implies convergence of $\sum {\frac{\sqrt a_n}n}$  with $a_n>0.$

Basically what I tried to show is that:

Since $\sum{a_n}$ converges, then $\lim a_n= 0$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$ , and so $\sqrt a_n \rightarrow 1$ when $n \rightarrow \infty,$ which means it is bounded. On the other hand, $\frac1n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and is always decreasing. Per theorem 3.42 in Rudin, that means $\sum{\frac{\sqrt a_n}n}$ also converges.

Is that correct or am I missing something? The solutions on the net appear to differ.

Comment: What does Theorem 3.4.2 say?

Comment: Welcome.  Please learn to typeset your questions in MathJax.  You'll get a lot more response if your questions are easier to read.  You can click the edit button to see how I edited your question.

Comment: Please see this post about the same question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1378353/is-this-correct-for-rudin-exercise-3-7-prove-the-series-is-convergent?rq=1

Comment: And your proof is incorrect since a sequence $(x_n)$ being bounded certainly does not imply that the series $\sum\frac{x_n}n$ converges.

Answer (score 3):

Cauchy-Schwarz:

\begin{align*}
\sum\dfrac{\sqrt{a_{n}}}{n}\leq\left(\sum a_{n}\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}\right)^{1/2}<\infty.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

- If $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt{a_n}=0$.
- To use theorem $3.42$ , which is the [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test), you need to show that $\sum_n \sqrt{a_n}$ is bounded, of which it is not known to be true.

Possible direction for the question:

- consider Cauchy-schwarz.

Comment: Thank you. Got it. Silly on my part.