# Series convergence from Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

So, in baby Rudin we have the exercise

> Prove that the convergence of $\sum a_n$ implies the convergence of $$\sum \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}$$ if $a_n \geq 0$

**My Approach**

Assume $\Sigma a_n$ converges and allow $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\sqrt{a_i}}{i}$.

By Cauchy-Schwarz we have $S_n^2 = (\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\sqrt{a_i}}{i})^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i^2} \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i $. Thus $\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n^2$ is finite. Consequently, $S_n$ converges.

Is this correct? I'm not sure if that's proper use of Cauchy-Schwarz or if I can apply limits like that. I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Yes, looks good!

Comment: [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1378353/is-this-correct-for-rudin-exercise-3-7-prove-the-series-is-convergent?rq=1), and also a duplicate at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2624359/rudin-chap-3-exercise-7?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Your proof is indeed correct.*

For the sake of variety, I would suggest an alternative to Cauchy—Schwarz, namely the [Am-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means): analogously to what you have written, for any $n\geq 0$,
$$
0\leq \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\sqrt{a_k}}{k} \stackrel{\tiny\rm (AM-GM)}{\leq} 
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k+\frac{1}{k^2}}{2} = \frac{1}{2}\left( \sum_{k=1}^n a_k + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2}\right) \leq \frac{1}{2}\left( \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}\right)
$$
Thus, the partial sums $S_n$ are bounding, and non-decreasing: $(S_n)_n$ converges by the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: Ah yes, it's been edited. I appreciate the other approach. Is there a good reference for these commonly used inequalities? I never really encountered AM-GM in class.

Comment: AM-GM, Cauchy—Schwarz, Minkowski, Jensen, and Holder are quite common; if you feel adventurous, [there are plenty others](http://www.lkozma.net/inequalities_cheat_sheet/ineq.pdf). @GoodMorningCaptain

Comment: Appreciate the response.

Comment: @GoodMorningCaptain You're welcome!