# How to prove convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt a_n}{n^\alpha}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Assume that $a_n >0$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n $ converges.
Show that for $\alpha>1/2$ the series
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt a_n}{n^\alpha}$$ converges as well

I think we can use Abel's convergence test but I'm not sure if that is the way to go

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz and you are done, since $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^{2\alpha}}$ is finite.

Comment: See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2863886/series-convergence-from-rudin) and [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1378353/is-this-correct-for-rudin-exercise-3-7-prove-the-series-is-convergent).

Comment: @KennyE Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By [**Cauchy–Schwarz inequality**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n^{\alpha}}\leq \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n}\,\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{2\alpha}}}$$

and

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{2\alpha}}$$

converges if and only if $2\alpha >1 \implies \alpha >\frac12$.

Answer (score 1):

hint:
The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality gives
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}\leq \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n}\,\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}}<\infty.$$

Comment: It would be $1/n^\alpha$ though, is that true even when $\alpha = 1$

Comment: $$\frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n} \le \frac12(a_n+\frac{1}{n^2})$$ 
 $\sum_na_n$ and $\sum_n\frac 1{n^2}$ are convergent

Answer (score 1):

Just to give an elementary proof (not relying on Cauchy-Schwartz), let $\alpha={1+p\over2}$. Then

$$\begin{align}
\left|\sqrt{a_n/n^{1+p}}-1/n^{1+p}\right|
&={\left|a_n/n^{1+p}-1/n^{2+2p}\right|\over\sqrt{a_n/n^{1+p}}+1/n^{1+p}}\\
&\le{\left|a_n/n^{1+p}-1/n^{2+2p}\right|\over1/n^{1+p}}\\
&=\left|a_n-1/n^{1+p}\right|\\
&\le a_n+1/n^{1+p}
\end{align}$$

and thus

$$\begin{align}
\left|\sqrt{a_n/n^{1+p}}\right|
&=\left|\sqrt{a_n/n^{1+p}}-1/n^{1+p}+1/n^{1+p}\right|\\
&\le\left|\sqrt{a_n/n^{1+p}}-1/n^{1+p}\right|+1/n^{1+p}\\
&\le a_n+2/n^{1+p}
\end{align}$$

and so

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\sqrt{a_n}\over n^\alpha}\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over n^{1+p}}\lt\infty$$

Comment: Very nice and extremely elegant way!